# Fixed vs variable amount of token

Tags: solidity, ico

A best practice question:

Is it better to create a fixed amount of tokens at the beginning of an ICO and release parts of it via crowdsales until reaching the total amount or is it better to mint amounts while creating crowdsales?

Is there any best practices regarding this?

A quick representation:

[image]

One of the obvious problems for case 2 is that funders might be irritated by the fact that we can mint token.

Comment: I think there is no proper answer to that. If you don't want/need minting, don't implement it, if you want/need it, do it.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Just wanted to check with the community if any best practices existed already.

Comment: Don't check the existing big tokens, 90% of them is just copy/paste of very basic token code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the spirit of decentralization, it would be best to use a fixed supply.

Minting them as you go dilutes the value of tokens which is a complication you may want to avoid.

Unless your project requires the ability to mint tokens for utility, or you have a clear reason for doing multiple rounds of crowdsales, it's best to steer clear.